# Sample and hold & analog shift register

Tags: capacitor, orcad, sample-and-hold

I have this circuit (see first picture.) it's an analog shift register where instead LF386 I use LF398H. This circuit must provide an hyperchaotic behavior for initial conditions x1(0) = l, x2(O) = O.l, and x3(O) = 0. The Sample & hold signal appears once per second and the signal looks like this.(see second picture) where the green signal is S/H1 and the blue one is S/H2. I made a simulation for 10 number generated by the circuit but I saw a problem in the interval [4;5]s the value should be -1.4025 V but in my case my signal stays for a short time in that value after that the voltage starts to increase(see the last picture.) and because of that my next number will have the wrong value. My question is why is this happen and how should I solve it.
BTW I tried with a smaller capacitance than 0.94uF and it didn't worked.
[image]
[image]
[image]